# Running flexunit4 tests for AIR app while building with maven and flexmojos

Tags: flash, intellij-idea, air, flexmojos, flexunit4

Is it possible? Since AIR is pure actionscript (no flex) and flexunit4 uses flex to build it's testrunner SWF when running the tests. Or am I missing something? Otherwise, is there any other unit testing library that can be used together with flexmojos in maven builds?

I'm using flexmojos version 6.0.1, flexunit 4.1.0 and AIR sdk 19.0. Any ideas? Have anyone managed to get it to work with a similar setup to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, Im testing my Air application (witch using Starling framework) and created repository with samples for it https://github.com/thenitro/flexunit_for_starling, there is a libs with flexunit-4.2.0-20140410-as3_4.12.0.swc which is pure as3 flexunit library, and also there is template for testing, when you setup everything and launch app you will see in traces if tests successfully passed.

Comment: Great, i'll have a look at that! Thanks!